# Javascript timer need to reset to 00 : 00 : 00

Tags: javascript, timer

I have a javascript code working as stopwatch timer. Now situation is: 
if  click start button then timer start and button toggle to stop button, If click stop then timer stop and time set to last situation.
But I need if click stop then timer will stop and reset to 00 : 00 : 00
I don't need extra reset button.

Thanks to all

```
    enter code here
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PadDigits(n, totalDigits)
        {
            n = n.toString();
            var pd = '';
            if (totalDigits > n.length)
            {
                for (i=0; i < (totalDigits-n.length); i++)


                {
                    pd += '0';
                }
            }
            return pd + n.toString();
        }

        var lastEndTime = null;
        var starttime = null;
        var endtime = null;

        function startTimer()
        {
            date = new Date();
            starttime = date;
            if(lastEndTime == null)
            {
                $('#history').html('');
            }
            $('#action').html('<img src=".png"><br>Stop Timer');
        }

        function stopTimer()
        {
            $('#action').html('<img src="play.png"><br>Start Timer');
            date = new Date();
            endtime = date;
            addRowToTable(starttime,endtime,lastEndTime);
            lastEndTime = endtime;
            endtime = null;
            starttime = null;
        }

        function addRowToTable(starttime,endtime,lastEndTime)
        {

            formattedStart = PadDigits(starttime.getHours(),2)+':'+PadDigits(starttime.getMinutes(),2)+":"+PadDigits(starttime.getSeconds(),2);
            formattedEnd = PadDigits(endtime.getHours(),2)+':'+PadDigits(endtime.getMinutes(),2)+":"+PadDigits(endtime.getSeconds(),2);

            seconds = parseInt((endtime.getTime() - starttime.getTime())/1000);

            lengthMinutes = parseInt(seconds/60);
            lengthSeconds = parseInt(seconds%60);
            lengthFormatted = PadDigits(lengthMinutes,2)+":"+PadDigits(lengthSeconds,2);




  }

        function toggleTimer()
        {
            if (starttime == null)
            {
                startTimer();
            }
            else
            {
                stopTimer();
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#action').click(function(kevent){
                toggleTimer();
            });

            $(document).keypress(function(kevent){
                $('#action').click();
            });
        });
    </script>




    <script type="text/javascript">   <!--javascript declaration-->

var sec = 0;  //declare global variable called sec and assign 0
var mins = 0;  //declare global variable called mins and assign 0
var hour = 0;  //declare global variable called hour and assign 0
function changestat(){   //declare a function called changestat()
var a=document.getElementById('butn').value;  //take the value by id called 'butn' and store that in a variable called 'a'
if(a=='Start'){  //declare if block if a is equal to 'Start'
document.getElementById('butn').value='Pause';  //change the value of 'butn' from 'Start' to 'Pause'
}  //end of if block
else if(a=='Pause'){  //declare else if block if a is equal to 'Pause'
document.getElementById('butn').value='Start';  //change the value of 'butn' from 'Pause' to 'Start'
} //end of else if block
stopwatch();  //call the function called stopwatch()
}  //end of changestat() function
function stopwatch(){ //declare a function called stopwatch()
var x=document.getElementById('butn').value; //take the value by id called 'butn' and store that in a variable called 'x'
if (x=='Pause'){  //declare if block if x is equal to 'Pause'
   sec++;  //keep adding '1' to the value of sec variable
  if (sec == 60) {  //declare if block if sec is equal to '60'
   sec = 0;  //set the value of sec to '0'
   mins = mins + 1;   //add '1' to current value of mins
}  //end of if block
  else {  //start of else block
   mins = mins;  //the value of mins remains same
}  //end of else block
  if (mins == 60) {  //declare if block if mins is equal to '60'
   mins = 0;   //set the value of mins to '0'
   hour += 1;   //add '1' to current value of hours
}  //end of if block
if (sec<=9) { //declare if block if sec is less than or equal to '9'
sec = "0" + sec;   //here we add 0 in front of the number  eg: 01
}  //end of if block
var stwa=document.getElementById('stwa'); //take the element by id called 'stwa' and store that in a variable called 'stwa'

stwa.value= ((hour<=9) ? "0"+hour : hour) + " : " + ((mins<=9) ? "0" + mins : mins) + " : " + sec;  //set the value in stwa text field  eg:00:02:01

SD=window.setTimeout("stopwatch();", 1000);  //this line will refresh the value of stwa textfield every second
}  //end of if block
}  //end of stopwatch() function
function reset(){   //declare a function called reset()
var stwa=document.getElementById('stwa');  //take the element by id called 'stwa' and store that in a variable called 'stwa'
sec = 0;  //set the value of sec to '0'
mins = 0; //set the value of mins to '0'
hour = 0;  //set the value of hour to '0'
stwa.value='00 : 00 : 00';  //display 00:00:00 in text field
changestat();  //call the function called changestat()
}  //end of reset() function

</script>  <!--end of the javascript -->


</head>


<body>




 <input type="text" value="00 : 00 : 00" id="stwa"/>  <!--create a inputfield which has stwa as id ans 00:00:00 as value -->


<br/><br/>

    <button onClick="changestat()" id="action"><img src="play.png"><br>Start Timer</button>
    <!---<input type="button" value="Reset" id="reset"  onClick="reset()"/>  <!--create a button which has reset as id and Reset as value and tell that to execute reset() function when it is clicked-->



        <input type="hidden"  value="Start" id="butn"  onClick="changestat()"/> <!--create a button which has butn as id and Start as value and tell that to execute changestat() function when it is clicked-->




</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Few changes needds to be done to your existing reset() method.

Just call the **reset()** method. I have removed calling **changestat()** method inside reset method.

```
 function reset(){   
    var stwa=document.getElementById('stwa');  
    sec = 0; 
    mins = 0; 
    hour = 0; 
    stwa.value='00 : 00 : 00'; 
    // remove this method call
    // changestat(); 
}
```

Call the **reset()** method inside **changestat()** like this:

```
 function changestat(){   
    var a=document.getElementById('butn').value;  
    if(a=='Start'){ 
        document.getElementById('butn').value='Pause';  
    }  
    else if(a=='Pause'){  
        document.getElementById('butn').value='Start';  
        reset();
    } 
    stopwatch(); 
}
```